# SQL request returns source id

Tags: mysql

I am doing this request:
`$uid = db_query("SELECT uid FROM tablename WHERE mail = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1")`

and get as result:

Resource id #310

But I want to get the uid. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
db_query("SELECT uid FROM tablename WHERE mail = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1");
```

just gives you an "answer", but you want the value of it. Try this:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT uid FROM tablename WHERE mail = 'test@test.com' LIMIT 1");
$row = db_fetch_array($result);
$uid = $row[0];
```

Comment: Cool. Many Thanks for your answer. I just opened a new post, maybe you can also have alook at it?